# Keep text together in a QHBoxLayout

Tags: qt, resize, qlabel, qlayout

I'm trying to make a hyperlink in my application. I got two label, one of them is the hyperlink.

```
labelPropulsedBy = new QLabel();
    labelPropulsedBy->setText(tr("Propulsé par "));
    labelPropulsedBy->setLayout(hboxLayout);

labelWebLink = new QLabel();
    labelTripleGear->setText("<a href=\"https://www.google.ca/\">Click Here!</a>");
    labelTripleGear->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
    labelTripleGear->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
    labelTripleGear->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
    labelTripleGear->setLayout(hboxLayout);
```

The problem is when i'm resizing my window, those two label get separated, like if there was to many spacing between them. How do you keep them together?

If there is a better way to do it please propose, i'mk trying to improve my coding habits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new horizontal spacer and add it behind the hyperlink label (or in front of the text label), this shall solve your problem. The code might looks like:

```
QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer;
horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
hboxlayout->addItem(horizontalSpacer);
```

Also, I recommend use designer to accerlate your app design speed!

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I don't use the designer because i'm new to programming and working directly on the code helps me learn new things. Can you explain why it did what it did? I can figure it's because when i expand my window, only teh QSpacerItem expand, not the complete layout, right?

Comment: The class QSpacerItem server as a container for excess space in the layout, hence in your case when hboxLayout expands, the spacer will extend (same for the vertical spacers). For a layout contains more than one spacer in the same direction, Qt has it's own mechanism to decides how to extend both of them. You can add multiple spacers in your app to see how they works. For more information, check this out: [http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qspaceritem.html#details](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qspaceritem.html#details)